# Can't se change? Am I running against a wall of obstinacy?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

I just wonder why the questions are duplicated (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75524/the-sound-change-the-light?noredirect=1#comment156943_75524 ) ?

Because I ask physics things in physics site (even       less quoting, and edited it as a physics problem),       and English questions in English site (ELL.SE).        Can't SE change? Am I running against a wall of obstinacy?

Comment: I'm going to move this to meta, but ... you aren't going to be happy with the outcome.

Comment: The link is dead so nobody will have a clue what this is about...

Comment: @dmckee im happy... for i can't ask here... thank you.

Comment: the link is alive for me, but dead for others? but sure alive for moderators , i think . @MichaelBrown

Comment: I see that [you know about meta-sites](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/764), and posted this rant to the main site none the less. Why is that?

Comment: @Lincoln The link definitely doesn't work for me, even after taking off the redirect stuff or the question name at the end... have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: @MichaelBrown It's a deleted post, so only he and >10k users can see it. He links to Emilio Pisanty's comment "This question asks exactly the same as the old one; therefore it is a duplicate. It is OK to ask about the physics but you've been indicated that this is unlikely to represent physical reality, which makes your original question off-topic (apart from ill-phrased)"

Comment: @dmckee: I think he doesn't have enough rep...

Comment: @Manishearth gotcha

Comment: @dmckee i don't know "posted this rant to the main site none the less."? more enlish?... my english level not so high as you...

Comment: er... what i indicated is not important, you can tell me where is wrong in physics. @Manishearth

Comment: @Lincoln: He meant that if you know about meta, why did you post it to the main ? .

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS i don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Lincoln: I know that, as I've commented above.

Comment: so someone migrated it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Physics.SE is for questions about physics.

Physics means observations of the way nature behaves , note: observations.

This rumble thing you are obsessing about is not an observation. It is a figment from the imagination of the author you have quoted. Physics.SE is not about interpreting dreams or visualizations or fairy land propositions or ....

You have also latched onto sonic weapons in your comments. Whales die because of sonic weapons so they do have strong effects. You could form a question on the lines:

> Can sonic weapons create waves?

or

> can a sonic boom move walls , made out of wood? stone? glass?

[The answer to this last](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w2AsGazCcg) is observational from the meteor that fell in Russia a while ago. Yes, they can have a lot of energy.

These are physics questions.Rumbles in the imagination of a writer are not, unless boundary conditions are strictly given, and then one can talk of a [gedanken experiment.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedanken_experiment) *Rumbles and oily sheens* are not boundary conditions for problem solutions.

Comment: Well, the oily sheen was *on the wall*, so it's sort of a boundary condition ;)

Comment: @ChrisWhite , yeah, why can't they tell me what's wrong in physics?  because if i post my question in sci-fiction of SE, they dont know too, it seems.

Comment: my internet speed is quite low to watch the youtube... but sometimes it works...

Answer (score 8):

The mere fact that you read something strange does not qualify it as a physics question. People can write anything they like, and no one and nothing stops them from writing unphysical nonsense. In fact, some of us read unphysical nonsense for entertainment, so we *pay* them to write unphysical nonsense.

We do not feel obligated to answer question about such writings, however, [and even say so](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) (note the bit about "fictional physics").

So, long answer short: your question is off-topic, and there is no version you can ask that will be answered here.

---

> am i running against a wall of obstinacy?

No, you are not.

We, on the other hand, are. You reposted that question twice, despite being told clearly and repeated that it was off-topic.

You seem bound and determined to push on us a question that clearly falls outside the bounds of what we accept. You are in the wrong on this, and the only polite thing for you to do is *quit it*.

---

Stack Exchange sites, like Physics.SE are *not* open forums where anything goes. We maintain high standards by enforcing tight bounds on what kind of content we accept and then using a crowd-sourced evaluation to sort content by quality.

We intend to continue maintaining those standards.

Comment: thanks for explanation. but people can't just explain why this text is nonsense in physics? but as i think , a sound like a sonic bomb can effect object. this question is low quality and off-topic...?

Comment: @Lincoln: Nope. That's not how the site works. You can add a feature request though, but it won't be accepted, most likely  .

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS then where can i ask this? in sci-fiction SE? seems they dont know physics.

Comment: @Lincoln: You'll have to ask it at SciFi.SE and wait for a while...

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS  actually ..., i can just ask it at scifi.se , just ask them what does it mean...